# Data doesn't wrap in tkinter Entry widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

I have data which looks like this.

```
tempList2=[{'Date': '21-Aug-2019', 'Day': 'Sunday', 'Status': 'This is the message. It should be wrapped!!'}, {'Date': '22-Aug-2019', 'Day': 'Monday', 'Status': 'Message Delivered'}, {'Date': '23-Aug-2019', 'Day': 'Tuesday', 'Status': 'Invalid Data found!! Please retry'}]
```

Next I am creating a `dataframe` for that Data. After that, I am using `tkinter` module to view the data.

Here's the Sample Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
a =[]
tempList2=[{'Date': '21-Aug-2019', 'Day': 'Sunday', 'Status': 'This is the message. It should be wrapped!!'}, {'Date': '22-Aug-2019', 'Day': 'Monday', 'Status': 'Message Delivered'}, {'Date': '23-Aug-2019', 'Day': 'Tuesday', 'Status': 'Invalid Data found!! Please retry'}]
for i in tempList2:
    print(i)
    print(type(i))
    b = list(i.values())
    a.append(b)
print(a)
tempList = a
df = pd.DataFrame(tempList)

# --- functions ---

def change(event, row, col):
    # get value from Entry
    value = event.widget.get()
    # set value in dataframe
    df.iloc[row,col] = value
    print(df)

# --- main --    

root = tk.Tk()

# create entry for every element in dataframe

rows, cols = df.shape

for r in range(rows):
    for c in range(cols):
        e = tk.Entry(root)
        e.insert(0, df.iloc[r,c])
        e.grid(row=r, column=c)
        # ENTER 
        e.bind('<Return>', lambda event, y=r, x=c: change(event,y,x))
        # ENTER on keypad
        e.bind('<KP_Enter>', lambda event, y=r, x=c: change(event,y,x))

# start program

root.mainloop()
```

Here's the output image I got:

[image: Output Image]

In the Output, the data doesn't get wrapped up. The data gets breaked. I need the data to be wrapped up with in the certain row. I have lots of data to be viewed. So I need a Scrollbar to access it. Help me with some solutions to wrap up the data and a scrollbar attached to the entire window.

Comment: Why don't use a ttk.treeview?

Comment: @1966bc, Thanks for the response. Yes. I used that  tree view in the tkinter listbox. But the listbox white background with no borders made my data difficult to read. So i shifted to this to make my data filled in box which makes me easy to view...since i am new to python, i can't find any better solution.

Comment: I (or someone else) might be able to help you, but don't have pandas installed — so I strongly suggest you put a [mre] in your question that doesn't require it...

Comment: @cheezeyes: ***"the data doesn't get wrapped"***: `Entry` does not support *wrap*, use [`Text`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) instead.

Answer (score 0):

As @stovfl commended, you can use [*tk.Text*](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm), which supports word wrap via the `WORD` keyword argument.

```
tk.Text(root, height=col_height, width=col_width, wrap=tk.WORD)
```

Two issues to handle:

1. Adjusting the height of all columns in a row to be the same.

   - You can find the largest string in a row and determine the height of the column based on that.
2. On `Enter` key the *Text* field will move the cursor down, sometimes hiding the text.

   - Strip the text and update the column on `Enter` key.

[image]

***Code***

```
# ...

def change(event, row, col):
    # get value from Entry
    value = event.widget.get("1.0", tk.END)
    # update column & set value in dataframe
    event.widget.delete("1.0", tk.END)
    event.widget.insert("1.0", value.strip())
    df.iloc[row, col] = value.strip()
    print(df)


root = tk.Tk()

rows, cols = df.shape

col_width = 30

for r in range(rows):
    longest_string = max(df.loc[r].values, key=len)
    # If you know last element will be longest,
    # No need to calculate longest string
    # col_height = len(df.loc[r].values[-1])//col_width +1
    col_height = len(longest_string)//col_width + 1
    # or int(len(col_text)/col_width)+1
    for c in range(cols):
        col_text = df.iloc[r, c]
        e = tk.Text(root, height=col_height, width=col_width, wrap=tk.WORD)
        e.insert("1.0", df.iloc[r, c])
        e.grid(row=r, column=c)
        e.bind('<Return>', lambda event, y=r, x=c: change(event, y, x))
        e.bind('<KP_Enter>', lambda event, y=r, x=c: change(event, y, x))

# ...
```